# How to creatre a list of beans (RedisRateLimiter) from application.properties in Spring Boot (Spring Cloud Gateway)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

For example, I have application.yml where I set properties to create different beans of RedisRateLimiter:

```
rate-limit:
  properties:
    - rate: 2
    - rate: 5
      ...
```

The thing is, that I dont know how many beans will be, I need to create them according to properties.
When I create @Bean List <"RedisRateLimiter>, and try to use any of them calling isAllowed() method, I get exception:
**RedisRateLimiter is not initialized at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.ratelimit.RedisRateLimiter.isAllowed**:

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("redisRateLimiters")
    public List<RedisRateLimiter> redisRateLimiters() {
        return properties.getProperties().stream()
            .map(rateLimit -> new RedisRateLimiter(..., rateLimit.getRate()))
            .toList();
    }
```

But when I create single bean @Bean RedisRateLimiter and use it, it works fine.

```
    @Bean
    public RedisRateLimiter redisRateLimiter1() {
        return new RedisRateLimiter(1, properties.getProperties().get(0).getRate());
    }
```

How can I create list of this beans properly (maybe with BeanFactoryPostProcessor somehow)?
P.S. I need this beans to limit requests to differents URLs, each with own rate. Maybe I am going to wrong direction and it can be done in other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to create `RedisRateLimiter` beans based on the application properties.

I am basing the answer over the following `RateLimitProperties` POJO definition:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rate-limit")
public class RateLimitProperties {
    
    private List<RateLimit> properties;
    
    public List<RateLimit> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
    
    public void setProperties(List<RateLimit> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
    
    public static class RateLimit {
        
        private int rate;
        
        // getters and setters
        
        public int getRate() {
            return rate;
        }
        
        public void setRate(int rate) {
            this.rate = rate;
        }
    }
}
```

Here down the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` implementation leveraging each `RateLimit` config item to create the respective bean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultBeanNameGenerator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class RateLimitingPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

  // Suggesting that you already have a `RateLimitProperties` class defined
  private final RateLimitProperties properties;

  public RateLimitingPostProcessorRateLimitProperties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    BeanNameGenerator beanNameGenerator = new DefaultBeanNameGenerator();
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;

    List<RateLimit> rateLimits = this.properties.getProperties();
    for (int i = 0; i < rateLimits.size(); i++) {
      RateLimit rateLimit = rateLimits.get(i);
      BeanDefinition beanDefinition = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(RedisRateLimiter.class)
        .addConstructorArgValue(rateLimit.getRate())
        .addConstructorArgValue(rateLimit.getDuration())
        .addConstructorArgValue(rateLimit.getKeyResolver())
        .getBeanDefinition();
      registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(beanDefinition), beanDefinition);
    }
  }

}
```

You should then update your application configuration to include the `RateLimitingPostProcessor` type:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

  private final RateLimitProperties properties;

  public AppConfig(RateLimitProperties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  @Bean
  public RateLimitingPostProcessor rateLimitingPostProcessor() {
    return new RateLimitingPostProcessor(properties);
  }

}
```

You should then be able to inject the `RedisRateLimiter` beans as follows:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("redisRateLimiters")
private List<RedisRateLimiter> redisRateLimiters;
```

Comment: But BeanFactoryPostProcessors require a no-argument constructor?